# Issue Installing entity framework 7

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm learning entity framework , but I'm having hard time to install it on my visual studio 2013. The guy on the video which I'm watching on he doesn't explain if I need extra components , he just says that they're gonna use SQLSERVER EXPRESS, so I downloaded SQLSERVER EXPRESS and when I try to perform the commands that he said to do in order to install entity I got issue, look at this :

Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -Version 7.0.0-rc1-final -Pre

Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework.Relational (≥ 7.0.0-rc1-final)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework.Core (≥ 7.0.0-rc1-final)'.
Install-Package : 'EntityFramework.Core' already has a dependency defined for 'Ix-Async'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -Version 7.0.0-rc1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPac 
   kageCommand

Does everyone have any idea how to solve it ?
Should I install a SQLSERVER EXPRESS plugin first then try to perform it ?

Comment: Why are you using RC1 when 1.1 RTM is released? Try this with the 1.1 packages and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: I reinstalled the nuget and it worked, thanks !